How to ignore Jmeter threads warm-up time which is dded to response time
I wanted to generate 1k user load in jmeter and hit at once i.e without any ramp up time. But I could see Jmeter thread creation and warm up time is also getting added response time.
So how can do this by avoiding Jmeter threads warmup time
Which is an ideal solution, using a synchronising timer or master slave setup
When I tried testing with ramp up time response time was as expected, but without ramp up it too high, which is very evident that threads warm-up time is also being added to response time

You can exclude ramp-up phase from the .jtl results file using i.e. Filter Results Tool which has --start-offset and --end-offset parameters so you can focus solely on "plateau" phase and ignore ramp-up period completely.
Filter Results Tool can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
